# Why didn't Muhammad execute the Jew who poisoned him?

Tags: hadith, sharia, prophet-muhammad, history, punishment

> Narrated Anas bin Malik: A Jewess brought a poisoned (cooked) sheep
> for the Prophet (ﷺ) who ate from it. She was brought to the Prophet
> and he was asked, "Shall we kill her?" He said, "No." I continued to
> see the effect of the poison on the palate of the mouth of Allah's
> Messenger (ﷺ) .
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 2617

Why didn't Muhammad execute her? What was her punishment for trying to poison Muhammad?

Answer (score 1):

The punishment for such an act would be execution at the discretion of the Prophet ﷺ, just as the behavior of the Sahaba and the Prophet ﷺ in this incident demonstrates.

In this instance the Prophet ﷺ forgave her, as one is free to forgive injuries against his own person. One [tradition](https://shamela.ws/book/5610/517) suggests that she was forgiven because she accepted Islam although this is disputed.

Also note that she was eventually killed in Qisas after Bishar ibn al-Bara' died from eating the same poisoned sheep:

> فأمر بها رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقتلت
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) then ordered regarding her and she was killed.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud 4513](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4513),  [Abu Dawud 4512](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4512), [Abu Dawud 4511](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4511)</sup>